# PHP Cookie Controls

Tags: php, variables, cookies

I am working with a logic operator to create a cookie containing a string of values depending on a user's traffic path through my website.

On my web page I have the following variable

```
$lgc_code = '3'
```

and my cookie control is set up as follows:

```
if ($lgc_code != '') {
    $lgc=$lgc_code;

    // check for cookie
    if (isset($_COOKIE['lgc_cntl'])) {

        // read cookie
        $lgc_codes=$_COOKIE['lgc_cntl'];

        // check for triggers in cookie
        $expEncArr = explode(",", $lgc_codes);
        foreach($expEncArr as $code){
            if ($code==$lgc_code) {$found='yes';}
        }

        if (isset($found)) {
            $lgc_codes=$_COOKIE['lgc_cntl'];
        } else {
            $lgc_codes=$_COOKIE['lgc_cntl'].','.$lgc;
        }

} else {
    $lgc_codes=$lgc;
}
// add campaign to cookie
setcookie('lgc_cntl',$lgc_codes,time() + (86400 * 365), "/", ".domain.com"); // 86400 = 1 day

} else {
    $lgc = '1';

    if (isset($_COOKIE['lgc_cntl'])) {

        // read cookie
        $lgc_codes=$_COOKIE['lgc_cntl'];

        // check for triggers in cookie
        $expEncArr = explode(",", $lgc_codes);
        foreach($expEncArr as $code){
            if ($code==$lgc_code) {$found='yes';}
        }

        if (isset($found)) {
            $lgc_codes=$_COOKIE['lgc_cntl'];
        } else {
            $lgc_codes=$_COOKIE['lgc_cntl'].','.$lgc;
        }

    } else {
        $lgc_codes=$lgc;
    }
    // add campaign to cookie
    setcookie('lgc_cntl',$lgc_codes,time() + (86400 * 365), "/", ".domain.com"); // 86400 = 1 day
}
```

This works for a single variable being passed from page to cookie but I need to be able to pass multiple variables at once while comparing them to the cookie.

For example if my page variable reads "1, 5, 10" and my cookie contains "1 and 10" then only variable 5 would need to be added.

Currently, if I add multiple variables on the page, the cookie simply duplicates them every time the page is loaded so I end up with "1,1,5,10,10"

How can I modify my code below to compare the variables and only add the ones that are not found in the cookie already?

Comment: How do you set multiple variables on a page? `$lgc_code = '1,5,10'`?

Comment: Yes, multiple variables would be set exactly as you assumed.

Comment: Then the result "1,1,5,10,10" comes from multiple pages with single `$lgc_code` or one page with `$lgc_code = '1,5,10'`?

Comment: If the variable has one code it works properly as it checks the code against the ones found in the cookie. If there are multiple codes in the variable it simply duplicates them in the cookie.

Comment: Just added an answer to handle multiple values, please see if it helps.

Comment: @sblteam - Your answer no longer posts single or multiple variable strings. I need to be able to use both depending on my pages so that some have multiple triggers and some have one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `$lgc_code` may contain comma separated values, then it should be converted to array before comparison. Try changing these lines

```
// check for triggers in cookie
$expEncArr = explode(",", $lgc_codes);
foreach($expEncArr as $code){
    if ($code==$lgc_code) {$found='yes';}
}
```

to

```
// check for triggers in cookie
$expEncArr = explode(",", $lgc_codes);
$thisPageArr = explode(",", $lgc_code);
$newCodes = array_diff($thisPageArr, $expEncArr);
if (!empty($newCodes)) { $found = 'yes'; }
```

Comment: When I modify the code as you outline it no longer posts single variables or multiple variables.

Comment: Is it able to detect single and multiple new codes successfully?

Comment: No, it doesn't seem to be detecting either of them with your code set up.